# match people by free time in schedule

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a website with a form section that allows users to specify which hours of the week they are free. (example: John Smith is free 4-7 on Tuesdays, and 8-9 on Wednesdays)

Then I want to run some server side code to pair users with similar blocks of time together.

I was wondering how should I design my database to support this functionality and what sort of algorithm would allow me to match similar users?

Comment: I will write the entire code for you and give you the entire database structure, tomorrow. http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: You need to define your problem a bit better - depending on the problem you're trying to solve, this is either relatively trivial or looking for a solution to an NP-hard problem.

Comment: @JonathanRich thanks for being subtle :)

Comment: What have you tried so far, post that? If you haven't I would try posting your question [here](http://www.freelancer.com/)

Comment: At first I thought you were a new user and couldn't comment.. but then I noticed you had enough reputation to comment. And I was disappointed.

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you :-(

Comment: Real fun when comments are thrown out of context xD

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'll try to make your database structure.

What I think is best is to divide the day in timeblocks, e.g. 00:00 - 01:00, 01:00 - 02:00, etc. You put them in a table

```
ID | day    | timestart | timeend
1  | Monday | 00:00     | 01:00
2  | Monday | 01:00     | 02:00
.....................
```

Note that the all columns are purely so that you know what you are referencing, except for the ID ofcourse.

Then you have your user table

```
ID | username | email             | ...
1  | John     | john@example.com  | ...
.....................
```

Then you have another table, time_off or sth

```
    user_ID  | timeblock_ID
    1        | 2
    1        | 8
...............
```

You put a FOREIGN KEY on both user_ID and timeblock_ID to reference to your other table

Then you can query this in the following way:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(timeblock_ID SEPARATOR ',') AS timeblocks FROM time_off WHERE user_ID=$id
```

and use the results to get every user with the same times off:

```
SELECT
   users.ID, users.username
FROM time_off
   LEFT JOIN users ON users.ID=time_off.user_ID
WHERE
    time_off.timeblock_ID IN($timeblocks)
GROUP BY users.ID
```

Not that hard, aint it? Implementation is up to you.